# IIS Url Rewrite query string limit problem

Tags: iis, https

Please help :)
We have a web project. Frontend and backend. Windows Server 2019 IIS8
A problem is that we have a SSL certificate only for subdomain xxx.xxx.de (This we cant change)

Frontend work over https. Backend is on some server running, but we can not reach server over https.
Only over http.

Me idea was use Url Rewrite. That even works, but!!!
URL Rewrite Module has query string limit.
Anything over 3000 characters will be cut off!!
Does anyone know the problem?

Upd:
I made all settings for IIS for requestfilter over all maxlength and http sys in registery.  If I only try over http, without url rewrite, then everything works with a 9000 byte query string. As soon as I turn on url rewrite, the query is cut off

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a query string limitation on URL rewrite module.
There are 2 related settings you can try:

1. Request filtering limitation and HTTP Runtime configuration.

[image]

[image]

2. HTTP.sys settings
   Reference this official document: [Http.sys registry settings for Windows - Internet Information Services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/iisadmin-service-inetinfo/httpsys-registry-windows).

   HTTP.sys can be configured by registry. You can create the following DWORD registry values under the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've tried it all.  If I only try over http, without url rewrite, then everything works with a 9000 byte query string. As soon as I turn on url rewrite, the query is cut off

Comment: Try to use failed request tracking to view detailed request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.